# ¿Cómo acceder a elementos de una vista parcial desde jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Quiero llenar una ***dropdownlist*** que tengo en una vista parcial desde una llamada ajax (jquery) que tengo en la vista principal.

Explico mi escenario:

En la vista principal tengo declarada un `<div>` que es donde mostraré una vista parcial u otra en función de la selección de un radio button.

```
<div id="direccion"></div>
```

Esto se hace mediante una llamada ajax desde jquery a una acción del controlador

```
public ActionResult GetTipoDireccion(string tipodir)
{
   if (tipodir.ToLower() == "local")
      return PartialView("_DirLocalPartial");
   else
      return PartialView("_DirForaneaPartial");
}
```

En `_DirLocalPartial` que es la que se muestra por defecto, tengo una ***dropdownlist*** que quiero llenar mediante una llamada ajax desde jquery a una acción del mismo controlador que proporciona los datos.

El problema es que desde jquery no consigo referenciar esta ***dropdownlist***, es como si no existiera.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Comment: Añado información a mi pregunta. En una de las vistas parciales existen diversas dropdownlist y además, alguna de ellas se ha de llenar en cascada, es decir, se ha de llenar en base a la selección que haga el usuario en otra.

Answer (score 0):

Partamos de la base que por el planteo que haces no se llena ningun dropdownlist usando ajax, sino que deberias tener en el cshtml el render del dropdownlist que inyectaras en sl div

Si quieres cargar un combo usando ajax primero debrias definir

```
<div id="direccion">
    <select id="combo1" />
</div>
```

entonces desde $.ajax deberias invocar un action que retorne json y no un partial view

[Populate (Bind) DropDownList using jQuery AJAX and JSON in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-Bind-DropDownList-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

como observaras en el ejemplo la idea es que el controller retorne un json

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxMethod()
{
    List<SelectListItem> customers = new List<SelectListItem>();
    NorthwindEntities entities = new NorthwindEntities();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        customers.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = entities.Customers.ToList()[i].CustomerID,
            Text = entities.Customers.ToList()[i].ContactName
        });
    }

    return Json(customers);
}
```

y que desde el html uses

```
var ddlCustomers = $("#ddlCustomers");
ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0" disabled = "disabled">Loading.....</option>');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
        $.each(response, function () {
            ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
        });
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

analiza el `success` como trabaja el json creando ls options

Pero remarco que no usas ningun partialview, sino que defines el `select` html y defines los options segun los datos que retorne en json

Si necesitas que sea html deberas invocar usando ajax he inyectar este en el div

[Return Partial View from Controller using AJAX in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-Partial-View-from-Controller-using-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

analiza en el articulo cuando usa un action devolviendo el partial

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(string customerId)
{
    NorthwindEntities entities = new NorthwindEntities();
    return PartialView("Details", entities.Customers.Find(customerId)); 
}
```

pero puntualiza a que asigna un model, porque vas a tener que cargar los options del combo cuando renderice y luego en el $.ajax usa

```
$('#dialog').html(response);
```

en tu caso seria

```
$('#direccion').html(response);
```

Comment: Leandro, el problema es que no puedo poner nada dentro del div que muestra las partial views ya que una contiene varias dropdownlist y la otra solo una. En resumen, que son bastantes diferentes los campos que contienen la una y la otra.

Comment: pero entonces deberas devolver html he inyectarlo en el div en lugar de json, pero el dropdownlist ya debera venir cargado con los options

Comment: agregue un adicional a la respuesta mencionando como inyectar html del render del partialview que invocarias desde ajax

Answer (score 0):

puedes acceder a los elementos de los partialViews teniendo un archivo JavaScript Global.Es decir,El archivo js se debe estar cargando en el _Layout que está cogiendo la vista y estás poniendo los partialViews y de ahí,a los elementos que quieras acceder,les asignas un id para poder referenciarlos de una manera más sencilla

Comment: Rubenchus, no me es factible incluir eso en el _Layout

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras llenar tu DropDownList mediante ViewBag, cargando la lista de valores en la acción de la siguiente forma:

```
public ActionResult GetTipoDireccion(string tipodir)
{

  ViewBag.Lista = MiLista.ToList();  //MiLista es List<Tipo>
  if (tipodir.ToLower() == "local")
      return PartialView("_DirLocalPartial");
   else
      return PartialView("_DirForaneaPartial");
}
```

En el cshtml lo recibes de la siguiente forma:

```
@Html.DropDownList("NombreDeTuDropoDownList", new SelectList(ViewBag.Lista, "Valor", "Texto"), "[Seleccionar]", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Donde `Valor` es el valor que vas a enviar al hacer el POST, y `Texto` es la descripción que aparecerá en el texto del DropDownList

Comment: Alfredo,como he puesto en el comentario que añadido a mi pregunta, en una de las vistas parciales existen varias dropdownlist que se han de llenar en cascada. Yo solo he visto como hacerlo con javascript, y en este caso, me encontraré con el mismo problema, que no podré referenciar el control desde jquery.